# How to store hash into db

Tags: database, perl, hash

I am using two hashes to store content from files, however instead of using memory I would like to store hash over the disk, could some suggest the logic on how to utilize db module.

( I just need the logic/references so that I can further work on it )

```
#!/usr/sbin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash1;
my %hash2;


while (<>) { 
        some statements...
        some statements...
        push @{$hash1{$pull1}}, $time1;

        some statements...
        push @{$hash2{$pull2}}, $time2;
}
```

Comment: There's tons of references on getting started [online](http://www.perl.com/pub/1999/10/DBI.html). Why don't you try for yourself and come back when you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simplest possible: [DB_File](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/DB_File-1.828/DB_File.pm). It's included in Perl standard modules, and doesn't need anything.

In case you need "serious" database - you will need [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.627/DBI.pm) module, and some [DBD::](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module&query=DBD%3A%3A) driver.

Comment: can I use Storable module : "http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html", I have a question about the module Storable, though. Storable just unloads content to a file, while keeping information in memory, true? What if one wanted to use the file for the hash of hashes rather than using memory?

Comment: Storable is a way to store data structure in file, and later on recover. It is not for live access to this data. Think about it more along the lines of "backup" than "database".

Comment: well, db_file, and dbi module is not installed in my prod environment, any other simple way you can suggest?

Comment: Are you sure DB_File isn't installed? It's been a core module since 1994.

Comment: DB_File has been included with the standard distribution of Perl for almost twenty years. What version are you using? And if DBI isn't installed, then why not install it?

Comment: Simple way? Use CPAN and install a module.

Comment: DBI is not installed by default. But other than that - there is not much that can help you. DBI is **the** standard for database access from Perl. At least as far as SQL databases go.

Comment: Interestingly, it looks that my perl 5.18 does *not* contain DB_File, even though it's listed in perldoc perlmodlib ?!

Comment: Well, we've two boxes, one having 5.8.0 ( no db_file), while 5.8.8 ( db_file) present. Anyway, we can use db_file. is there any sample code you can provide to store hash code?

Comment: The sample is in perldoc - First link I provided in answer.